# JIRA - Get List of Unresolved Issues

Tags: api, jira

I'm brand new to JIRA API programming.
I need to get a list of unresolved issues.
From the API, the function getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit() looks like a likely candidate.  And I have also read on another SO thread that an issue is unresolved if the system Resolution field contains no value.
So, how would I construct the call, e.g (I'm fishing here) in pseudocode:

```
getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit(resolution=NULL)
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: which Jira version? which remote API?

Comment: If you're using JIRA 4.4 or later I'd try to use the REST interface first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JIRA RPC documentation, [getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) uses a predefined JIRA filter to retrieve issues.  It will not work with a caller supplied query or search terms.

To use this method, you will need to define a filter in JIRA so it can be referenced in the [getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) call.

An alternative would be to use [getIssuesFromJQLSearch](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getIssuesFromJqlSearch%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) which works with a caller supplied JQL expression to retrieve issues.  The JQL to return issues with now resolution would be `resolved is EMPTY`.